# Standardising data table in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to standardise a data table (http://www.brucehardie.com/datasets/CDNOW_master.zip) however unable to do so using scale(data[-1]). All of the data table is getting combined in to a single column.
What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```r
#load data
prelim.data <- read.csv(file.choose())

#understand data structure and variables
summary(prelim.data)
str(prelim.data)
prelim.data$transaction_date <- format(as.Date(as.character(prelim.data$date), format="%Y%m%d"),"%d-%m-%Y")

#standardize data
test <- prelim.data
test$num_of_items <- as.numeric(test$number_of_cd)
test$date <- NULL
test$customer_id <- NULL
test$transaction_date <- NULL
test$number_of_cd <- NULL
test_stzd <- scale(test[-1])
```

Comment: That file is not a `csv`, it is space-separated and will not work properly with `read.csv`. E.g. - `read.csv(text="a b\n1 2")` gives one column instead of two.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data with `dput()` and `head()`? I'm not keen to download a zip.

Comment: Please just post us a snippet of a few lines of your file. If it's not CSV but is fixed-width format, try `read.fwf`. Otherwise you'll have to wrestle with `read.csv`, or else try `data.table::fread` or `readr`. There are tons of duplicate questions here on SO.

Comment: The file is saved as .csv

The original file was a .txt file which I converted to .csv
The file has 69659 obs. of 5 variables reduced to two variables in the 'test' data table.

A snippet of the data is provided below:

...
customer_id date number_of_cd transaction_value
1 19970101 1 11.77
2 19970112 1 12
2 19970112 5 77
3 19970102 2 20.76
3 19970330 2 20.76
3 19970402 2 19.54
...

Comment: You may access the file here:
https://rnotebook.io/anon/bbb911e12257d54f/edit/CDNOW_master.csv#